# how to consume mvc 4 webapi service using httpwebrequest

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, httpwebrequest

I am consuming mvc 4 webapi service .

```
string postData = string.Format("user={0}&pwd={1}", "me", "123");
            HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://sb2212.myaddresss.in/api/values/pavan?id=1&srt=2");
            webRequest.Method = "post";
            webRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            webRequest.ContentLength = postData.Length;
            try
            {
                using ( StreamWriter requestWriter2 = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream()))
                {
                    requestWriter2.Write(postData);
                }

                using (StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    // dumps the HTML from the response into a string variable
                    postData = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
                }
```

reponse is "OK" but I am getting  empty response.
output is " ".

Answer (score 0):

you can use HttpClientPostAsJson, post object need to be Json object not form encoded.

```
    var postData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(string.Format("{user={0},pwd={1}}", "me", "123"));


    using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    string URL= "http://sb2212.myaddresss.in/api/values/pavan?id=1&srt=2";
                    var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(URL, postData );
                    var result= await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    var resultobj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result)

                }
```

Comment: HttpClient not working for me.it shows namespace couldnot be found

Comment: using System.Net.Http; if you have .net 4.0 https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http/

Comment: using Newtonsoft.Json; install with nuget